# AngularJS - ng-switch not working as expected

Tags: angularjs

I am using AngularJS with twitter bootstrap. The fiddle for my issue can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fXKgC/).

The HTML code in question here is:

```
<button type="button" class="btn" ng-repeat="tool in toolBar">
    <div ng-switch on="tool.action">
        <i class="icon-plus-sign" ng-switch="insert"></i>
        <i class="icon-edit" ng-switch-when="edit"></i>
        <i class="icon-trash" ng-switch-when="delete"></i>
    </div>
</button>
```

and the scope is:

```
$scope.toolBar = [
    {
        "action": "insert"
    },
    {
        "action": "edit"
    },
    {
        "action": "delete"
    }        
];
```

Problem is that I want the icons to be displayed only one per button but somehow the more than two icons are shown.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are missing "when" on the first icon. If you fix that it will work.

Comment: Thanks! Could you just mention this as the answer so that I can close this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a `when`.

Replace your html with

```
<button type="button" class="btn" ng-repeat="tool in toolBar">
    <div ng-switch on="tool.action">
        <i class="icon-plus-sign" ng-switch-when="insert"></i>
        <i class="icon-edit" ng-switch-when="edit"></i>
        <i class="icon-trash" ng-switch-when="delete"></i>
    </div>
</button>
```

and it should work fine.